# `<module:Templates>': uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite (NameError) using Sinatra / Unicorn

Tags: ruby, nginx, sinatra, unicorn

I'm new in the Ruby world. I created my first app using Sinatra, and I'm having some trouble on my production server.

When I run `unicorn -c randmovie_unicorn.rb` on my local machine, it works just fine. But in production, I get this error:

```
<module:Templates>': uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite (NameError)
```

In my `randmovie_unicorn.rb` file:

```
preload_app true  
working_directory "./"  
listen 8006  
worker_processes 2  
timeout 30
```

I'm not using HAML or anything similar.

Could somebody help me with that? Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

I think it's a bug in tilt 2.0.0 or in sinatra.
Specify tilt version in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'tilt', '~> 1.4.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem.

Make sure you don't have tilt 2.0.0 installed, and that you have a version of tilt that sinatra does support. For some reason bundler does not respect sinatra's dependencies properly, so you have to specify them explicitly.

Current tilt dependency for latest version of sinatra (1.4.4 as of this writing) is

```
gem 'tilt', '>= 1.3.4', '~> 1.3'
```