# Taps server error `<module:Templates>': uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite (NameError)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, taps

I'm trying to migrate my sqlite3 database to a postgresql, but i can't get passed this error.

when i run `taps server sqlite://db/development.sqlite3 [user] [password]`

I keep getting `/Users/phillipjarrar/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sinatra-1.0/lib/sinatra/base.rb:298:in <module:Templates> : uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite (NameError)`

Comment: Try `gem install tilt`

Comment: Whats the version of sinatra and tilt installed ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that's a current bug on version 2.x of Tilt. You need to downgrade it to `~ 1.4`.

Here's a link to another SO question about Tilt for reference.
[`<module:Templates>': uninitialized constant Tilt::CompileSite (NameError) using Sinatra / Unicorn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20648394/moduletemplates-uninitialized-constant-tiltcompilesite-nameerror-using)